# Why itertools.cycle() function using maximum ram?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm learning itertools module in python now.While learning I came to know `itertools.cycle()` function.

In my python3.7 IDLE I tried `list(itertools.cycle([1,2,3]))` statement.After hitting enter button my laptop's ram is being consumed highly.Surprisingly it used my laptop's maximum ram.Why this is happening?

Comment: What result did you expect to get? [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) runs indefinitely.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, I can't see it having any value to anyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `list(cycle([1,2,3]))` is equivalent to

```
lst = []
for x in cycle([1,2,3]):
    lst.append(x)
```

The loop never terminates, because the `cycle` object *always* has a next element to yield, so `lst` grows indefinitely, stopping only when your machine as run out of memory to allocate to the list.